Why are value and options not populating in a custom dataTable combobox column edit template?
I'm defining a custom column for a Lightning dataTable component to hold a Lightning combobox like this:
{
    label: 'Down Payment Type',
    fieldName: 'DownPaymentType__c',
    type: 'picklistColumn',
    editable: true,
    typeAttributes: {
        placeholder: 'Choose Type',
        options: downPaymentTypeOptions,
        variant: 'label-hidden',
        value: {fieldName: 'DownPaymentType__c'}
    }
}

I'm defining the options in the same file, prior to the class definition, like this (with the intention of loading them dynamically once this is working):
const downPaymentTypeOptions = [
    {label: 'Cash', value: 'Cash'},
    {label: 'Trade', value: 'Trade'},
    {label: 'Both', value: 'Both'},
    {label: 'None', value: ''}
];

I have a custom component extending dataTable which accepts the column object above. It looks like this:
export default class CashTradeTable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        picklistColumn: {
            template: customText,
            editTemplate: customPicklist,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['name', 'label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context', 'variant']
        }
    };
}

Here's the edit template (customPicklist):
<template>
    <lightning-combobox name="picklist"
                        data-inputable="true"
                        label={typeAttributes.label}
                        value={editedValue}
                        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}
                        options={typeAttributes.options}
                        variant={typeAttributes.variant}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>

However, while properties like placeholder and variant work properly, options does not. I've also realized that value isn't transferring to the edit template either, regardless of whether I assign typeAttributes.value or editedValue.
Note that only the editTemplate values aren't being updated. If I substitute the edit template for the standard template it's working--the options are populated. I need the options to populate in the edit template.
I've tried using a getter in the class with no improvement. I have checked the value of the columns object in the main component and the options value is correct.
The thing looks like this initially:

And like this in edit mode:

I've also verified that it's not a truncation/obscured view thing; I can see that the dropdown element is empty. Why aren't the values populating?

Related resources:

Create a Custom Data Type
Make a Custom Data Type Editable


The answer was found in a repository for a custom component. Apparently I needed to reference columnDef in my attribute values, as:
options={columnDef.typeAttributes.options}

This was not indicated in any Salesforce documentation or other discussions I encountered, but it resolved my options and value issues. Oddly, this wasn't necessary for label, placeholder, etc., though it also works for them.
